# Where does system-config-printer store the config files?

Tags: printing

Where are printers stored that are created using this interface?

I want to back them up.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the back-end that is used. If [cups](https://linux.die.net/man/5/printers.conf) (what would be the default in Ubuntu) ...

```
 /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

> Description
>
> The printers.conf file defines the local printers that are available. It is normally located in the /etc/cups directory and is generated automatically by the cupsd(8) program when printers are added or deleted.

If you backup/restore these files makes sure you do that when cups is not running. It is very picky about editing this file manually.

Comment: The file printers.conf does not contain the driver. If you don't backup the driver as well, tbis configuration file would be useless. Nowadays, drivers are less and less needed, because most printers are compatible with driverless printing, but in my case with HP M255dw, I had to use the driver that can be obtained from the printer with a USB connection and stored as a PPD file in `/etc/cups/ppd`.  Anyway, one might need to backup and restore these PPD files as well to avoid searching for them again.